# How can I make a .Net 6 dll understand MessageBox and DialogResult

Tags: c#, forms, dll, .net-6.0

I am moving some old code up to .Net6 from very old versions and am finding the new project references hard to set up.
I am trying to make a dll that has some knowledge of windows forms using C# in VScommunity 2022 and .net6.0.
I picked the C# WPF Class library as the default project to build from.
I am able to get  the DLL to talk to my exe for basic operations but I am unable to get it to compile when it has references to things like MessageBox and DialogResult in it.
I cannot find any way to get VS to recognise these references.  It wont let me add  `using System.Windows.Forms;` (error CS0234 Forms does not exist in Windows)  and I cant see any way to add via project properties.
What am I missing ?
Here is an example of what I am trying to compile

```
    public class JFIO
    {
        public static StreamReader? OpenReader(string filepath, bool bQuiet)
        {
            StreamReader sr = null;
            if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                if (!bQuiet)
                    MessageBox.Show("Input file not found\n" + filepath);
                return sr;
            }
            DialogResult r = DialogResult.OK;
            while (r != DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                try
                {
                    sr = new StreamReader(filepath);
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    r = MessageBox.Show("Error opening file\n" + filepath + "\n" + e.ToString(), "", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);
                }
            }
            return sr;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the input.  This is just a simple dll that I want to use in several of my forms based EXE programs to manage file opening, IO etc.

I found that if, instead of the WPF Class Library, I use the WindowsFormControl Library as a root for the DLL I am able to access the MessageBox etc OK and achieve what I want but it will only allow the .Net framework 4.7.2, no 5.0 offered,  Why is this ?

Comment: For .NET, instead of adding a reference, you need to download/install the appropriate NuGet package. Also see Tools => Options => NuGet Package Manager => General => Package Management => Package Management => Default package management format: PackageReference

Comment: I'm not sure I'd strive to find a way for a class library project to show messageboxes

Comment: The assembly is `System.Windows.Forms`: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/main/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/MessageBox.cs

Comment: Agreed, for a library you should just let the exception bubble up, or throw one where relevant. Your library may be running headless (in a service for example)

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't answer your question or only partially, but i am also porting old .net code and couldn't understand how to check for dialog result in a wpf .net 6 application.
in doing so i found this:

```
DialogBoxWithResult dialogBoxWithResult = new DialogBoxWithResult();
// Open dialog box and retrieve dialog result when ShowDialog returns
bool? dialogResult = dialogBoxWithResult.ShowDialog();
switch (dialogResult)
{
    case true:
        // User accepted dialog box
        break;
    case false:
        // User canceled dialog box
        break;
    default:
        // Indeterminate
        break;
}
```

so instead of checking for DialogResult.OK we now how to check for true/false ...

good luck, Chris

Answer (score 0):

In your C# project go to Properties and under Application--> General you can set Enable Windows Forms for this project.

If you do so, you can only distribute to Windows computers as before (not platform independent).